# Copy full file path into Copy-Paste-Clipboard

Tags: emacs, clipboard

I am looking for a method to save the current full filename of the file I'm working on into my copy-paste buffer to be able to switch to another program and paste e.g. 'C:\some\path\file.txt'.

I have tried the following method but it actually does pretty much nothing:

```
(defun clip-file ()
  "Put the current file name on the clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (if (equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
                      (file-name-directory default-directory)
                    (buffer-file-name))))
    (when filename
      (x-select-text filename))))
```

The function `x-select-text` originates from `interprogram-cut-function`, which is mentioned in the help file of the Copy-shortcut `M-w` as a variable containing a function, that is called to save the kill-ring for external programs, so the text may be copy-pasted from Emacs to e.g. Firefox.

I'm using Emacs on my Windows-PC and am therefore not sure, if `x-select-text` would work, since AFAIK it has something to do with the X-Server from Linux?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. `x-*` is still used for non X-Window stuff.  From time to time they clean things up by creating a function that has the more generic name, without the `x-`. But in this case `x-select-text` is the one.

Comment: But it obviously doesn't work for me. Does it for you?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine for me, with any Emacs version (20-24). E.g., if I use that in Emacs and then use `C-v` in some other Windows application. But `default-directory` should be expanded, using `(expand-file-name default-directory)` or better yet `(file-name-directory default-directory)` (or `(directory-file-name (file-name-directory default-directory))` if you do not want the final `/`). If you do not expand the dir, you can get `~/foobar/`, for example.

Comment: If you are in dired mode already, you don't need it. `w` will copy the file name, `c-u w` will copy the relative file name and `c-u 0 w` will copy the absolute file name.

Comment: Okay, it works now :)    There was a problem with my .emacs-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code mentioned in my question works, it was a problem with my configuration of .emacs-file, because I didn't restart Emacs properly.

Therefore use:

```
(defun clip-file ()
  "Put the current file name on the clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (if (equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
                      (file-name-directory default-directory)
                    (buffer-file-name))))
    (when filename
      (x-select-text filename))))
```

Comment: Works great! But I wonder if there is a way to copy it in a way that I can paste it into an emacs buffer? It seems to get added to my os's clipboard, but not to the emacs clipboard. Usually when I copy something, I can paste it into an emacs buffer.

Answer (score 7):

```
(defun copy-buffer-file-name-as-kill (choice)
  "Copy the buffer-file-name to the kill-ring"
  (interactive "cCopy Buffer Name (F) Full, (D) Directory, (N) Name")
  (let ((new-kill-string)
        (name (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                  (dired-get-filename)
                (or (buffer-file-name) ""))))
    (cond ((eq choice ?f)
           (setq new-kill-string name))
          ((eq choice ?d)
           (setq new-kill-string (file-name-directory name)))
          ((eq choice ?n)
           (setq new-kill-string (file-name-nondirectory name)))
          (t (message "Quit")))
    (when new-kill-string
      (message "%s copied" new-kill-string)
      (kill-new new-kill-string))))
```

Comment: This works great, but puts the result in the kill ring instead of the OS clipboard (as the requester wanted).

Comment: I tried replacing kill-new with x-select-text but it didn't work in Aquaemacs (GNU Emacs 23.4.1)

Comment: It works perfectly ("as-is") with the developer build of Emacs Trunk (built `--with-ns`) on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8 -- I can paste the result into any application, such as another text editor, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon this question when searching for how to copy the file path to clipboard with Spacemacs. So for completeness and to help other people that may also find this question in their searches, notice that Spacemacs has this functionality already binded to:

`SPC f y`